# I am not able to get product info using Ionic 6 and In App Purchase 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a problem with [App Purchase 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) on my Ionic 6. On the apple side, it's all set as it is supposed to be regarding setting up the product. The product I set is non-consumable with the appropriate price and all the following information. The code I implemented, according to the documentation, is below:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IAPProduct, InAppPurchase2 } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-purchase-2/ngx';
import { AlertController, ModalController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

const PRODUCT_PRO_KEY = 'io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-in-app-purchase-modal',
  templateUrl: './in-app-purchase-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./in-app-purchase-modal.component.scss'],
})

export class InAppPurchaseModalComponent {

  isPro = false;
  products: IAPProduct[] = [];
  p: IAPProduct;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private store: InAppPurchase2,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private modalController: ModalController
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Only for debugging!
      this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;
      
      this.store.register({
        id: PRODUCT_PRO_KEY,
        type: this.store.NON_CONSUMABLE
      });
      this.store.when(PRODUCT_PRO_KEY)
        .approved(p => {
          console.log('11111');
          console.log(p);
          p.verify();
        })
        .verified(p => {
          console.log('22222');
          console.log(p);
          p.finish();
        });
      
      this.store.refresh();
    });
    
  }
}
```

Once I start the application using Xcode, and navigate to the page, the same one is showing NULL values all the time:

```
2022-08-15 10:55:15.921736+0200 App[97981:2276286] KeyboardPlugin: resize mode - native
2022-08-15 10:55:15.964434+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc] Initialized.
⚡️  Loading app at capacitor://localhost...
⚡️  [log] - onscript loading complete
⚡️  [log] - Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1204 ms
⚡️  [log] - Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1167 ms
⚡️  WebView loaded
⚡️  [warn] - [Deprecation Warning]: ion-slides has been deprecated and will be removed in Ionic Framework v7.0. We recommend using the framework-specific integrations that Swiper.js provides, allowing for faster bug fixes and an improved developer experience. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides for more information including migration steps.
⚡️  To Native ->  App addListener 42043855
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: state: io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable -> registered
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: ios -> product io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable registered
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: store.trigger -> triggering action refreshed
To Native Cordova ->  InAppPurchase debug InAppPurchase1003760721 ["options": []]
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: ios -> initializing storekit
To Native Cordova ->  InAppPurchase setup InAppPurchase1003760722 ["options": []]
2022-08-15 10:55:27.809276+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: setup: OK
⚡️  [log] - InAppPurchase[js]: setup ok
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] INFO: ios -> storekit ready
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: ios -> loading products
⚡️  [log] - InAppPurchase[js]: load ["io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable"]
To Native Cordova ->  InAppPurchase load InAppPurchase1003760723 ["options": [<__NSArrayM 0x600001e0aa60>(
io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable
)
]]
2022-08-15 10:55:27.821689+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: load: Getting products data
2022-08-15 10:55:27.821962+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: load: Set has 1 elements
2022-08-15 10:55:27.822114+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: load:  - io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable
2022-08-15 10:55:27.823491+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: load: Starting product request...
2022-08-15 10:55:27.828971+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: load: Product request started
2022-08-15 10:55:28.326150+0200 App[97981:2276510] InAppPurchase[objc]: BatchProductsRequestDelegate.productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:
2022-08-15 10:55:28.326431+0200 App[97981:2276510] InAppPurchase[objc]: BatchProductsRequestDelegate.productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: Has 0 validProducts
2022-08-15 10:55:28.327391+0200 App[97981:2276510] InAppPurchase[objc]: BatchProductsRequestDelegate.productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: sendPluginResult: (
        (
    ),
        (
        "io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable"
    )
)
2022-08-15 10:55:28.328429+0200 App[97981:2276510] InAppPurchase[objc]: processPendingTransactionUpdates
⚡️  [log] - InAppPurchase[js]: load ok: { valid:[] invalid:["io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable"] }
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: ios -> products loaded
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: state: io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable -> invalid
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] WARNING: ios -> product io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable is NOT valid (io.ionic.cryptoalerts.pro.nonconsumable)
⚡️  [log] - [store.js] DEBUG: update()
To Native Cordova ->  InAppPurchase appStoreReceipt InAppPurchase1003760724 ["options": []]
⚡️  [log] - InAppPurchase[js]: loading appStoreReceipt
2022-08-15 10:55:28.347321+0200 App[97981:2276286] InAppPurchase[objc]: appStoreReceipt:
⚡️  [log] - InAppPurchase[js]: infoPlist: io.ionic.cryptoalerts,0.12.0,16809984,null
2022-08-15 11:07:03.603736+0200 App[97981:2279571] [SOServiceConnection] <SOServiceConnection: 0x6000011ad0a0>: XPC connection interrupted
2022-08-15 11:07:25.000107+0200 App[97981:2288372] [XPC] Handle connection with error: Connection interrupted
```

As you see, I have no product details such as price, name and few more. Any help, please :-).